# How do you display list of objects inside of other list of objects in UWP windows 10 apps C

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I am working on an app that uses list of objects with a list of different objects inside of the object. I am currently displaying the initial list of objects using the flipview class to swipe through the initial list of objects. However I cant seem to display the list of objects inside of each object in the initial list. for example if I have a list of objects called "Months" with the ability to swipe through the months. I would like to display the list of objects called "Days" inside of that "Month" object.

Here is my sample XAML code:

```
 <Grid Background="{ThemeResource SystemColorWindowColor}">
    <FlipView Name="MonthFlipView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="585" Margin="30,23,0,0"
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="295" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Months}">
        <FlipView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemsPanel>

        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <xmal:DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Month">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="18" Foreground="White" Margin="0,25" Text="{x:Bind year }"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="18" Foreground="White" Margin="0,25" Text="{x:Bind name }"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="18" Foreground="White" Margin="0,25" Text="{x:Bind season }"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="18" Foreground="White" Margin="0,25" Text="{Binding Source= }"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </xmal:DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>

</Grid>
```

When I try and bind to the list of objects inside of the object the list of objects do not show up as an option to bind to. How should I move forward?

Comment: What does your Month class look like?

Answer (score 0):

Given the following objects:

```
public class Month
{
    public IEnumerable<int> Days { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And your viewmodel has a list of `Month` objects, then you can bind directly to the `Days` property within the FlipView ItemTemplate as such

```
<FlipView Name="MonthFlipView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Months}">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Month">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
                <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Days}">
                    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                </GridView>
            <StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```